# Noise of a translucent object when aligned with a plane with the method of alignment tool "snap"

Tags: faces

I have found that by having translucent objects and using the snaping tool (edge mode) in a plane that serves as the floor of the scene, there is an overlap in the center of the object.

[image: overlapping]

**How could you avoid this overlap of faces in cycles without having to move the plane?**

*Edit mode*

[image: wire]

Comment: Is the bottom surface (the one aligned with the plane) totally flat?

Comment: The object has a bit of bevel at the edges.

Comment: @Corrado_M please show at least the back face mesh structure along with the rendered view, to spot what is causing that